# Function take() error - Link Analysis Research using Spark Mllib

Tags: apache-spark, scala

I'm doing a Link Analysis project on Retail Industry using Spark Mllib. My schema is:

ID -    Long
Chain - Int
Dept -  int
Category -  Int
Company - Long
Brand   -   Long
Date -  Date
ProductSize - Int
ProductMeasure  - Chararray
PurchaseQuantity - Int
PurchaseAmount - Double

And the code that I'm using is:

```
scala> import org.apache.spark._
scala> import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
scala> import org.apache.spark.util.IntParam
scala> import org.apache.spark.graphx._
scala> import org.apache.spark.graphx.util.GraphGenerators

scala> case class Transactions(ID:Long,Chain:Int,Dept:Int,Category:Int,Company:Long,Brand:Long,Date:String,ProductSize:Int,ProductMeasure:String,PurchaseQuantity:Int,PurchaseAmount:Double)
defined class Transactions

scala> def parseTransactions(str:String): Transactions = {
     | val line = str.split(",")
     | Transactions(line(0).toLong,line(1).toInt,line(2).toInt,line(3).toInt,line(4).toInt,line(5).toInt,line(6),line(7).toInt,line(8),line(9).toInt,line(10).toInt)
     | }

scala> val textRDD = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/transactions.csv")  

scala> val transactionsRDD = textRDD.map(parseTransactions).cache()

scala> val products = transactionsRDD.map(Transactions => (Transactions.ID,Transactions.Chain,Transactions.Dept,Transactions.Category,Transactions.Company,Transactions.Brand,Transactions.Date)).distinct

scala> products.take(1)
```

But when I submit the last line I'm getting the following error:

```
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 1) / 7]16/08/24 04:56:13 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "id"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:441)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:483)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toLong(StringLike.scala:230)
 at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toLong(StringOps.scala:31)
 at $line65.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.parseTransactions(<console>:38)
 at $line67.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
    at $line67.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
 at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
 at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.unrollSafely(MemoryStore.scala:285)
 at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.putInBlockManager(CacheManager.scala:171)
 at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:78)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:268)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
 at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/08/24 04:56:13 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "id"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:441)
 at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:483)
 at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toLong(StringLike.scala:230)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toLong(StringOps.scala:31)
    at $line65.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.parseTransactions(<console>:38)
    at $line67.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
 at $line67.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
 at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.unrollSafely(MemoryStore.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.putInBlockManager(CacheManager.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

16/08/24 04:56:13 ERROR scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
16/08/24 04:56:13 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "6.67"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toInt(StringLike.scala:229)
 at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toInt(StringOps.scala:31)
 at $line65.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.parseTransactions(<console>:38)
 at $line67.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
    at $line67.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
 at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
 at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.unrollSafely(MemoryStore.scala:285)
 at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.putInBlockManager(CacheManager.scala:171)
 at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:78)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:268)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
 at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/08/24 04:56:13 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, localhost): java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "6.67"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
 at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toInt(StringLike.scala:229)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toInt(StringOps.scala:31)
    at $line65.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.parseTransactions(<console>:38)
    at $line67.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
 at $line67.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
 at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.unrollSafely(MemoryStore.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.putInBlockManager(CacheManager.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "id"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:441)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:483)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toLong(StringLike.scala:230)
 at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toLong(StringOps.scala:31)
 at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.parseTransactions(<console>:38)
 at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
 at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
 at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
 at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.unrollSafely(MemoryStore.scala:285)
 at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.putInBlockManager(CacheManager.scala:171)
 at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:78)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:268)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
 at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
 at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
 at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
 at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
 at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
 at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1843)
 at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1856)
 at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1869)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1328)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1302)
 at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:47)
 at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:52)
 at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:54)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:56)
 at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:58)
 at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:60)
 at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:62)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:64)
 at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:66)
 at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:68)
 at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:70)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:72)
 at <init>(<console>:74)
 at .<init>(<console>:78)
 at .<clinit>(<console>)
 at .<init>(<console>:7)
 at .<clinit>(<console>)
 at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1045)
 at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1326)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:821)
 at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:852)
 at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:800)
 at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
 at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
 at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
 at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
 at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
 at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1064)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
 at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
 at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
 at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
 at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
 at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "id"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:441)
 at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:483)
 at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toLong(StringLike.scala:230)
 at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toLong(StringOps.scala:31)
 at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.parseTransactions(<console>:38)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.unrollSafely(MemoryStore.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.putInBlockManager(CacheManager.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Anyone knows why I'm getting this error?  I was supposed to return the array that I created...

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `toInt` call tries to transform a string that contains non-numeric characters.

Comment: I was thinking and the error could be int "line(6)" where I've the field date and I'm passing as String

Comment: You are never parsing it to a date right? Just keeping it as a String. I don't know any Scala so I might be off but I do know Spark. It's a NumberFormatException so it's trying to parse a string into a number. Are there try except constructions in Scala? And try to take a few rows of the TransactionsRDD before doing the distinct. Remove some toInt to see if the problem is there (remove all of them maybe)

Comment: Jan when I remove all .toInt I'm getting this error :

def parseTransactions(str:String): Transactions = {
     |      val line = str.split(",")
     |      Transactions(line(0).toLong,line(1),line(2),line(3),line(4),line(5),line(6),line(7),line(8),line(9),line(10))
     |      }
<console>:47: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: Int
            Transactions(line(0).toLong,line(1),line(2),line(3),line(4),line(5),line(6),line(7),line(8),line(9),line(10))

Do you know why?

Comment: Because you defined your Transactions class to still require Int

Comment: Get it ;) Many thanks!!! I need to put all the fields as a String when I define the class

Comment: You are trying to parse the header line. BTW this isn't a data science question but just a programming question really.